# Why the if statement in this coffeescript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I am new to coffeescript and am having a hard time understanding some code I found in the atom.io project. Here is the code from the cursor.coffee file (line 306 at the time of this question)

```
  moveToEndOfWord: ->
    if position = @getEndOfCurrentWordBufferPosition()
      @setBufferPosition(position)
```

which gets turned into

```
Cursor.prototype.moveToEndOfWord = function() {
  var position;
  if (position = this.getEndOfCurrentWordBufferPosition()) {
    return this.setBufferPosition(position);
  }
};
```

What I am having a hard time understanding is the why the if statement? Since the assignment operator is being used instead of the equality operator inside the condition statement, I understand the code to read

```
Cursor.prototype.moveToEndOfWord = function() {
  var position = this.getEndOfCurrentWordBufferPosition();
  return this.setBufferPosition(position);
};
```

Any light that could be shed onto what is happening here would be great.

Comment: It's a shorter way of writing `var position = this.getEnd...; if (position) { this.setBuffer... }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An assignment expression has a value, that being the value that was assigned. So that `if` statement is using an assignment as a *side effect* of testing the buffer position.

Comment: Duh.. I missed the if( position) after assignment shown in blender's comment